# Error found while running a code

Tags: python

```
def plane_ride_cost(city):
    if city== 'Charlotte' :
        return 183
    if city== 'Tampa' :
        return 220
    if city== 'Pittsburgh' :
        return 222
    if city == 'Los Angeles':
        return 475
    plane_ride_cost('city')


# Cost of flying to a city. This code is verified in Jupyter! It works.


def hotel_cost(nights):
    return 140*nights


# Cost of staying in a hotel. This code is verified in Jupyter! It works.


def rental_car_cost(days):
    if days<3:
        cost = 40*days
    if days>=7:
        cost = 40*days - 50   # Discount
    elif days>=3:
        cost = 40*days - 20    # Discount
    return cost

# cost of renting  a car.

def trip_cost(city, days, spending_money):
    return rental_car_cost(days) +  plane_ride_cost('city') + hotel_cost(days)
#total cost
```

it shows following error.

```
trip_cost('Tampa', 0, 0) raised an error: maximum recursion depth exceeded in cmp
```

Now I have run each code individually in Jupyter and it is working well. But not as a one code.

Answer (score 3):

you call this function within itself:

```
def plane_ride_cost(city):
    if city== 'Charlotte' :
    ....
    plane_ride_cost('city')
```

this is an infinite recursion. the python interpreter fortunately stops before that and raises a recursion exception.

to fix you probably need to remove that line (what was it supposed to do anyway? `'city'` is no valid `city`.